# product image missing from backend after updating

Tags: product, image, ce-1.9.2.3

After upgrading to Version 1.9.2.3 will not product images are displayed in the backend only in frontend. All run on a single web server with the same rights on apache user.
Someone who can help?

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue I had to revert change the permissions to more realistic values, 775 for folders and 644 for files. These can be changed here;

lib/Varien/File/Uploader.php

line 219, change 0640 to 0644
line 541, change 0750 to 0755

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, images only showed in the front-end. I haven't discovered the cause but the solution was to change web browser.

This is what I've discovered thus far.

**These browsers DON'T WORK**

- Google Chrome Version 58.0.3029.110 (64-bit)
- Microsoft Edge 40.15063.0.0

**These browsers DO WORK**

- Microsoft Internet Explorer 11.413.15063.0
- Mozilla Firefox 53.0.3 (32-bit)

Answer (score 0):

Just as a followup to what Kane said since I cannot comment, if you find that it works on the browsers he mentioned it's probably because **Adobe Flash Player** is disabled on the others. Try enabling it on **Chrome/Edge** or whatever browser you are using and see if that fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try running this cammand within your magento2 root dir

```
sudo bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/magento2/
```

magento2->Your dir